# How to retrieve the element text using GetAttribute method?

Tags: c#, selenium, getattribute

How can I get this element's text:

```
<span jsan="7.widget-pane-link,0.role" style="">Hi</span>
```

In other words, how can I get the text `Hi` by Using attribute `GetAttribute("jsan")`?

Comment: its span.innertext or span.innerhtml

Comment: I will try to use javascript innerHtml

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the text **Hi** from the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for `ElementIsVisible()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as solutions:

- Using *CssSelector* and [Text](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Text.htm) property:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("span[jsan*='widget-pane-link'][jsan$='role']"))).Text);
  ```
- Using *XPath* and [GetAttribute()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) method:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//span[contains(@jsan, 'widget-pane-link') and contains(@jsan, 'role')]"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```